# Mouseover mouseout JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events

I'm trying to make an element appear when the client's mouse is over it and disappear when it leaves the object but it is not working. It's very simple code I can't understand why it isn't working. Here is the code:

```
var earlyBirds = document.getElementById("earlyBirds");
var block = document.getElementById("block");

var appearenceEB = function(){
    block.style.visibility = visible;
}

var dissappearenceEB = function(){
    block.style.visibility = hidden;   
}

earlyBirds.addEventListener("mouseover", appearenceEB);
earlyBirds.addEventListener("mouseout", dissappearenceEB);
```

Comment: Please add your html code as well.

Comment: it's missing quotes, visible and hidden is concatenated as a string

Answer (score 3):

`visible` and `hidden` should be in quotes.

```
var appearenceEB = function(){
    block.style.visibility = "visible";
}

var dissappearenceEB = function(){
    block.style.visibility = "hidden";   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it functional, wrap `addEventListener` in `window.onload` as following:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="earlyBirds">earlyBirds</div>
<div id="block">block</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var appearenceEB = function(){
    block.style.visibility = "visible";
}

var dissappearenceEB = function(){
    block.style.visibility = "hidden";   
}

window.onload = function(){
    earlyBirds.addEventListener("mouseover", appearenceEB);
    earlyBirds.addEventListener("mouseout", dissappearenceEB);
};
```

[**DEMO - 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/294w425j/1/)

Other way is to create two separate functions for `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events, as following:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="earlyBirds" onmouseover="mouseOver();" onmouseout="mouseOut();">earlyBirds</div>
<div id="block">block</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function mouseOver(){
    document.getElementById('block').style.visibility = "visible";
}

function mouseOut(){
    document.getElementById('block').style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

[**DEMO - 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/1gbkf24s/)

Better to add your javascript to head tag otherwise in body using javascript tag. Also, set your elements prior visibility to none using CSS as following:

**CSS:**

```
#block {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```